# Joining user table for message table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating message conversation script in PHP mysqli. I want to display username from users table I want to know how to join message table to users table.

Here is my source code

```
users table

userid username
```

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from pm where (from_id=? and to_id=?) || (to_id=? and from_id=?)")){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $from_id,$to_id,$from_id,$to_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay try this:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN pm ON pm.userId=users.id WHERE from_id=? AND to_id=?")){
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $from_id, $to_id);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203787/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-thunberg-joining-user-table-for-message-table).